# Why does [NSSet containsObject] fail for SKNode members in iOS8?

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, nsset, sknode

Two objects are added to an `NSSet`, but when I check membership, I can't find one of them.

The test code below worked fine in iOS7 but fails in iOS8.

```c
SKNode *changingNode = [SKNode node];
SKNode *unchangingNode = [SKNode node];
NSSet *nodes = [NSSet setWithObjects:unchangingNode, changingNode, nil];

changingNode.position = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

if ([nodes containsObject:changingNode]) {
  printf("found node\n");
} else {
  printf("could not find node\n");
}
```

Output:

> could not find node

What happened between iOS7 and iOS8, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SKNode`'s implementations of `isEqual` and `hash` have changed in iOS8 to include data members of the object (and not just the memory address of the object).

The [Apple documentation for collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/collections/Articles/Sets.html) warns about this exact situation:

> If mutable objects are stored in a set, either the hash method of the
>   objects shouldn’t depend on the internal state of the mutable objects
>   or the mutable objects shouldn’t be modified while they’re in the set.
>   For example, a mutable dictionary can be put in a set, but you must
>   not change it while it is in there.

And, more directly, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html):

> Storing mutable objects in collection objects can cause problems.
>   Certain collections can become invalid or even corrupt if objects they
>   contain mutate because, by mutating, these objects can affect the way
>   they are placed in the collection.

The general situation is described [in other questions in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368173/mutable-objects-in-collections).  However, I'll repeat the explanation for the `SKNode` example, hoping it helps those who discovered this problem with the upgrade to iOS8.

In the example, the `SKNode` object `changingNode` is inserted into the `NSSet` (implemented using a hash table).  The hash value of the object is computed, and it is assigned a bucket in the hash table: let's say bucket 1.

```c
SKNode *changingNode = [SKNode node];
SKNode *unchangingNode = [SKNode node];
printf("pointer %lx hash %lu\n", (uintptr_t)changingNode, (unsigned long)changingNode.hash);
NSSet *nodes = [NSSet setWithObjects:unchangingNode, changingNode, nil];
```

Output:

> pointer 790756a0 hash 838599421

Then `changingNode` is modified.  The modification results in a change to the object's hash value.  (In iOS7, changing the object like this did *not* change its hash value.)

```c
changingNode.position = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
printf("pointer %lx hash %lu\n", (uintptr_t)changingNode, (unsigned long)changingNode.hash);
```

Output:

> pointer 790756a0 hash 3025143289

Now when `containsObject` is called, the computed hash value is (likely) assigned to a different bucket: say bucket 2.  All objects in bucket 2 are compared to the test object using `isEqual`, but of course all return NO.

In a real-life example, the modification to `changedObject` probably happens elsewhere.  If you try to debug at the location of the `containsObject` call, you might be confused to find that the collection contains an object with the exact same address and hash value as the lookup object, and yet the lookup fails.

**Alternate Implementations** (each with their own set of problems)

- Only use unchanging objects in collections.
- Only put objects in collections when you have complete control, now
  and forever, over their implementations of `isEqual` and `hash`.
- Track a set of (non-retained) pointers rather than a set of objects: `[NSSet setWithObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:(void *)changingNode]]`
- Use a different collection.  For instance, `NSArray` will be affected by changes to
  `isEqual` but won't be affected by changes to `hash`.  (Of course, if
  you try to keep the array sorted for quicker lookup, you'll have
  similar problems.)
- Often this is the best alternative for my real-world situations: Use an `NSDictionary` where the key is the `[NSValue valueWithPointer]` and the object is the retained pointer.  This gives me: quick lookup of an object that will be valid even if the object changes; quick deletion; and retention of objects put in the collection.
- Similar to the last, with different semantics and some other useful options: Use an `NSMapTable` with option `NSMapTableObjectPointerPersonality` so that key objects are treated as pointers for hashing and equality.