# Creating a convenience method for a subclassed SKNode object for all iOS versions

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, xcode6, sknode

I´m creating a convenience method for a subclassed SKNode object using the code below. This seems to be working fine. What bugs me, is that the SKNode Class Reference explicitly states that the -init symbol is only available for iOS 8.0 and later. The deployment target for my app is iOS 7.1.

```
+ (instancetype)postGameContent
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        [self setupContent];

    } return self;
}
```

I´m worried that the init method in my code is transferred up the inheritance chain for iOS7.1, bypassing whatever is initialized by SKNode´s own convenience method (+ node) or initializer (- init). Is there a chance that my code will result in somewhat different nodes (or even objects) depending on iOS version number? Related to this, when I write:

```
return [[self alloc] init];
```

Xcode 6 autocompletion gives "init" a red strikethrough without explaining why ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Laqb0.jpg)). Is this because of potential version issues, or can it be other reasons?

Comment: There must be a message with the red strikethrough. Could you post that as well? I do not think it has to do with the init method, rather it could be the reference to self.

Comment: Thank you, I have provided a screenshot: http://imgur.com/nGFEJIl

Comment: I highly doubt this poses any problem, most likely the documentation is simply incorrect.

Comment: Yes, maybe this bugs me more than it should. The code works as intended. Still, is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have found out:

- The class method [SKNode node] calls init, which makes the above code safe in terms of potential bypass and missing proper node initialization.
- When it comes to "node consistency" across iOS versions, this doesn't help much, as the SKNode class have been subject for major revisions in iOS 8.

Here's how I found out:

If the - init symbol was only available in the iOS 8 version, that would mean that SKNode's class factory method called another initializer than init, at least for iOS 7. To test this, I replaced the alloc init with node in the convenience method and added a log message in the init method:

```
+ (instancetype)postGameContent
{
    return [self node];
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        NSLog(@"init called!");

    } return self;
}
```

Now, if the node method calls init, my subclass initializer will tell me, and it did for both iOS 8 and iOS 7. In my eyes, this makes the explicit iOS 8 specific - init symbol in the Class Reference redundant. Please correct me if I am wrong.

In addition to new initializers, properties and methods, the iOS 8 SKNode class have also changed the implementation of the hash and isEqual methods. This have resulted in strange behavior in various ways, inculding [collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143970/why-does-nsset-containsobject-fail-for-sknode-members-in-ios8) and [physics](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1067393#1067393). This means that either way, your iOS 7 nodes might behave differently in iOS 8.

Why the red strikethrough, I don't know. I have a request going with Apple DTS, and will report back if I hear anything about it.

**UPDATE:** I have been in contact with the Holy Church in California. The confusion was based on a misunderstanding on my behalf. I assumed one could – both technically and in compliance with the API contract - initialize any object with the alloc] init] process, for example:

```
SKNode *node = [[SKNode alloc ] init];
```

This assumption is wrong. One should always use an initializer specified in the Framework Reference. This means for iOS 7.1 and below, there is only one way to initialize SKNode objects, namely using the +node symbol. It doesn’t matter that it is technically possible to initialize SKNode using init, even when we know init is overridden in the SKNode Class in iOS 7. It breaks the API contract.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of overriding the init method, you could perform the needed operations in the convenience method itself.

```
+ (instancetype)postGameContent
{
    MyNode* node = [super node]; //Create node from superclass, i.e. SKNode
    [node setupContent]
    return node;
}
```

This actually makes it even more safe with regards to version compatibility.

Comment: Maybe I´m not understanding the Apple documentation correctly. Given that Objective-C Classes also are objects (p. 22), and that "Using self in a class factory method means that you’re referring to the class itself" (p. 42) and not an instance; using [[self alloc] init] makes it possible for subclasses to create the correct instance without overriding the method. (Source: Programming with Objective-C, Apple Developer)

Comment: Hmm... You are right, and I may not be totally clear about it myself. However, I found an article which may help: http://mintknow.biz/zener/2014/09/17/how-to-morally-subclass-sknode-when-there-is-no-init-method/

Comment: Thanks, but the link leaves me where I´m currently standing. To my understanding, it is also incorrect about about SKNode being a subclass of NSObject. UIResponder is SKNodes superclass, which inherits from NSObject. But again, thank you for going out of your way for this.

Comment: That was actually how I did it originally, but isn't that downcasting? I know that works as well, but in terms of good code design, should be reconsidered. I'm also considering to not subclass SKNode, and instead create a class that creates objects and handles them for the scene.

Comment: That is essentially what the above code has become. You can create a factory class, but even that needs to be subclassed from something, so why not just use SKNode?

Comment: For two reasons: (1) It would retain my original problem with node creation and (2) entail unecessary inheritance. That being said, I'm not sure my (current) solution is any better, which is subclassing NSObject and importing the SpriteKit Framework. Some more informational scavenging is necessary. I have contacted Apple Developer Support regarding this matter, and I will report back as soon as I hear from them.